# Receiving notification when a question you voted to close gets edited

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-close, notifications

I was just wondering if it was possible to get a notification when a question that I've voted to close gets edited?  I think it would be helpful for the site, as I'm sure if the question was edited so that it is greatly improved then I (and others) would like to retract my vote to close.

Comment: Really, that'd be way too much noise for me. There is a reopen review queue, posts edited after closing go to that queue for the community to handle.

Comment: But that's a "Reopen" queue.  And, really, how many questions make it out of there alive?  I'm not sure what you mean about "noise", it'd just be a number at the top of your screen.  There was a well-received similar question about getting a notification of an edit on downvoted content, so this seems like a solid request.

Comment: It'd be a large number for active users like me. I *know* that most of those are not going to show enough of an improvement for me to retract my close vote, most bad questions are simply not improved to the standard we require. So I'll never actually look at the notifications, making it just noise, something to ignore.

Comment: If the post has been improved enough to no longer need closing, the close votes will cease being cast and the existing votes simply expire.

Comment: "how many questions make is out of there alive?" Just about all that are sufficiently improved. Even though that's a really small percentage of those entering it, a vanishingly small percentage of those closed, and an infinitisimally small part of those which should have been closed.